# Read WIFI_SLEEP_POLICY on Nexus 7

Tags: android

I'm building an app that must keep the Wi-Fi connection alive in the background. Therefore it is important that the device doesn't auto shutdown Wi-Fi when the device goes to sleep.

Therefore I would like to check for the current Wi-Fi Sleep policy on the device, and if it is the wrong one, I would like to inform the users about it and link them to the right settings page so they can change it.

In order to do this I`ve written the following code:

```
@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
@SuppressLint({ "InlinedApi", "NewApi" })
private void checkWiFiPolicy() {
    ContentResolver cr = this.getContentResolver();
    int apiLevel = 0;
    try { apiLevel = Build.VERSION.SDK_INT; } catch (Exception e) {}

    int apiIndWifiSleepPolicyDefault = -1;
    int apiIndWifiSleepPolicyNever = -1;
    int apiIndWifiSleepPolicyNeverWhilePlugged = -1;
    int currentWifiPolicy = -10;
    if (apiLevel < 17) {
        apiIndWifiSleepPolicyDefault = Settings.System.WIFI_SLEEP_POLICY_DEFAULT;
        apiIndWifiSleepPolicyNever = Settings.System.WIFI_SLEEP_POLICY_NEVER;
        apiIndWifiSleepPolicyNeverWhilePlugged = Settings.System.WIFI_SLEEP_POLICY_NEVER_WHILE_PLUGGED;
        try {
            currentWifiPolicy = Settings.System.getInt(cr, android.provider.Settings.System.WIFI_SLEEP_POLICY);
        } catch (Exception e) {}
    } else {
        apiIndWifiSleepPolicyDefault = Settings.Global.WIFI_SLEEP_POLICY_DEFAULT;
        apiIndWifiSleepPolicyNever = Settings.Global.WIFI_SLEEP_POLICY_NEVER;
        apiIndWifiSleepPolicyNeverWhilePlugged = Settings.Global.WIFI_SLEEP_POLICY_NEVER_WHILE_PLUGGED;
        try {
            currentWifiPolicy = Settings.Global.getInt(cr, android.provider.Settings.Global.WIFI_SLEEP_POLICY);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    if (currentWifiPolicy == apiIndWifiSleepPolicyDefault) {
        ALog.d(ALog.TAG_ACTIVITY, "Detected WifiSleepPolicy: DEFAULT");
    } else if (currentWifiPolicy == apiIndWifiSleepPolicyNever) {
        ALog.d(ALog.TAG_ACTIVITY, "Detected WifiSleepPolicy: NEVER");
    } else if (currentWifiPolicy == apiIndWifiSleepPolicyNeverWhilePlugged) {
        ALog.d(ALog.TAG_ACTIVITY, "Detected WifiSleepPolicy: NEVER WHILE PLUGGED");
    } else {
        ALog.d(ALog.TAG_ACTIVITY, "Detected WifiSleepPolicy: UNKNOWN");
    }
}
```

This code however fails on a Nexus 7 (Android 4.3, Gen. 1):

```
W/System.err(5318): android.provider.Settings$SettingNotFoundException: wifi_sleep_policy
```

Even if I try the legacy approach (the one I use for apiLevel < 17), I get exactly the same error. 
(Note that I am able to read other System settings such as System.Global.DATA_ROAMING)

Any Ideas on how I can read this Setting on a Nexus 7?

Comment: Why not just hold a `WifiLock`?

Comment: Because the system setting WIFI_SLEEP_POLICY is able to overwrite the Wi-Fi locks, so that won't work. (And I'm already holding one)

Comment: "Because the system setting WIFI_SLEEP_POLICY is able to overwrite the Wi-Fi locks, so that won't work" -- do you have a reference for this? That seems rather odd, as the point behind a `WifiLock` is to temporarily override such rules, just as the point behind a `WakeLock` is to temporarily override the CPU-can-go-to-sleep rules.

Comment: Hi CommonsWare, I don`t have any official reference for this, but when I run a fileserver in the background of my app (having acquried a WakeLock and WiFiLock), then my server goes offline after a couple of minutes because the WiFi gets disabled by the system. 

This only happens when the System `WIFI_SLEEP_POLICY` is set to `WIFI_SLEEP_POLICY_DEFAULT`. If I manually change the policy to `WIFI_SLEEP_POLICY_NEVER`, then it does work.